# Kendo ui grid hierarchical error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have akendo grid and I need to add hierarchly details for each row.

```
 function detailInit(e) {
            $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: e.data.Emails
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: e.data.Emails
                    },
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "EmailAddress", title: "Email" },
                ]
            });
        }
```

Why Do i get the error? `alert (e.data.Emails[0].EmailAddress )` works

Comment: post what error you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you specify schema.data and assign read to an array?

Simply try with the data field.

e.g.

```
function detailInit(e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: e.data.Emails                    
            },
            columns: [
                { field: "EmailAddress", title: "Email" },
            ]
        });
    }
```